# go client watch etcd event has failed

Tags: go, etcd

when i use the etcd client `go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3` to watch the etcd event, i found that i will receive many responses with empty events.the
log below:

> ime="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00" level=debug msg="ETCD watch response:
>   {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0 Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[]
>   CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false Created:false closeErr:
>   cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135" time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00"
>   level=debug msg="ETCD watch response: {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0
>   Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[] CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false
>   Created:false closeErr: cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135"
>   time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00" level=debug msg="ETCD watch response:
>   {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0 Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[]
>   CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false Created:false closeErr:
>   cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135" time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00"
>   level=debug msg="ETCD watch response: {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0
>   Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[] CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false
>   Created:false closeErr: cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135"
>   time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00" level=debug msg="ETCD watch response:
>   {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0 Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[]
>   CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false Created:false closeErr:
>   cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135" time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00"
>   level=debug msg="ETCD watch response: {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0
>   Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[] CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false
>   Created:false closeErr: cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135"
>   time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00" level=debug msg="ETCD watch response:
>   {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0 Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[]
>   CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false Created:false closeErr:
>   cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135" time="2019-10-27T20:39:13+08:00"
>   level=debug msg="ETCD watch response: {Header:{ClusterId:0 MemberId:0
>   Revision:0 RaftTerm:0} Events:[] CompactRevision:0 Canceled:false
>   Created:false closeErr: cancelReason:}" file="backend.go:135"

tips: backend.go:135 is:
fmt.Printf("%v", resp), the resp is received from watchChan

```golang
   func (e *EtcdClient) watchWithOptions(ctx context.Context, key string, opts ...clientv3.OpOption) clientv3.WatchChan {
    if e.client == nil {
        return nil
    }

    key = e.withPrefix(key)

    return e.client.Watch(ctx, key, opts...)
}

// WatchPrefix watch the kvs change with same prefix
func (e *EtcdClient) WatchPrefix(ctx context.Context, prefix string) clientv3.WatchChan {
    return e.watchWithOptions(ctx, prefix, clientv3.WithPrefix(), clientv3.WithPrevKV())
}
```

i excepted the put, delete events,but the actual output is invalid empty events

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   []string{"localhost:2379", "localhost:22379", "localhost:32379"},
        DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil {
        // handle error!
    }
    defer cli.Close()
    ctx := context.Background()
    rch := cli.Watch(ctx, "foo")
    for wresp := range rch {
        for _, ev := range wresp.Events {
            fmt.Printf("%s %q : %q\n", ev.Type, ev.Kv.Key, ev.Kv.Value)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: watch using etcdctl]

In case if you haven't seen, check out the [example](https://godoc.org/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3#example-Watcher--Watch) from the doc

To debug further, do you mind sharing your code?